# How to mock a method from a class that it is from jar (JAVA)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I can't resolve an issue that it has been bugging me out last week.

It is possible to mock a class that it is inside a jar so I don't call the real method.

**Example:**

> 3 Classes (Class Person, Class PersonTest, Class PersonExternalJar)
>
> ```
> public class Person{
>
>      private PersonalExternalJar pej;
>
>      public void methodA(){
>           *do some stuff*
>            pej = new PersonalExternalJar();
>            ArrayList people = pej.doSomething(AnyString,AnyString,AnyObject);
>            *do some stuff*
>            People2 p = new People2(); //  This class it is somewhere in my project lets say
>            String SomePeople = p.doSomeStuff();
>
>      }
> }
>
>
> @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
> public class PersonTest{
>      @Mock private People2 p;
>      @Mock private PersonExtenarlJar pej; // I get an error like I can't find this class or some internal thing of this class.
>
>      @InjectMocks private Person  pr;
>
>      @Test
>      public void personTest(){
>           *do some stuff*
>            pr = new Personal();
>            //try both declare the class and not declaring the class
>            //when I do the next 
>            Mockito.doReturn("anything").when(p).doSomeStuff(); // WORKS
>            Mockito.doReturn(AnyArray).when(pej).doSomething(AnyString,AnyString,AnyObject) // CAN'T DO THIS 
>            //Doesn't work
>            //Alternatively I tried to take off the annotation mock and do the following.   
>             PersonalExternalJar pej = Mockito.mock(PersonalExternalJar.class) 
>             //Still doesn't work.
>      }
> }
> ```
>
> As I understood about unit testing it is to isolate the class and try its behaviour without calling external methods (that's why I use mockito).

Mockito core version 1.10.19 
Junit     4.12.

I hope someone can give me a solution or make me see another perspective or make me understand that I might be confused about concepts.

Comment: This is what has been known to happen when you tightly couple your code to 3rd party code you can't control. Encapsulate external dependencies behind abstractions you control and explicitly inject them into your dependent classes. makes mocking and maintaining your code more flexible.

Comment: @dherik Yes, it is a class that i can modify.

Comment: @nkosi  It is a 3rd party code that i cant control but it give us access to database. I need it to couple my code because it is mandatory. I have somehow find a way to used and fake the calls. But thanks.

Comment: I don't think that SpringJUnit4ClassRunner supports the Mock and InjectMocks annotations of Mockito. To enable this functionality you need to RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class). And the assignment "pej = new PersonalExternalJar();" does not seem to make sense. It will override the injected mock. You could initialize it at the declaration (or at the constructor).

Comment: @StefanGroßmann Hi, thanksk for answering. Sorry i wanted to write MockitoJunitRunner.class. My mistake.   What i dont understand it is what u mean by pej = PersonalExternalJar() doest not seem to make sense. The class Person needs to initialize the class somewhere right? in order to use their methods. Person it is the class i am testing, the others classes inside, i need to mock them.

Comment: @StefanGroßmann you mean that i need to declare them People2 and PersonalExternalJar in a constructor? Why?

Comment: At your class Person you assign the attribute pej with "new PersonalExternalJar()". This will override the Mock which has been injected by Mockito. And btw "pr = new Personal();" in your test will replace your mock with a class. Maybee some tutorial might help you to undersand the concept: http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations

Comment: @StefanGroßmann i get about pr = new Personal(); tried this, tried that to understand the concept. It is not about seeing a easy tutorial which i get the idea, and i get that i override personal. But what i dont get is that i am overriding PersonaExternalJar. So if i initialize the classes in the constructor, i wont have problems to mock that class?  The problem is when i tried to do MOCK(PERSONALEXTERNALJAR:CLASS) is that i get a not found class weird error and if i dont mock the class it is trying to call the real method.

Comment: I need more info than " I get an error like I can't find this class or some internal thing of this class" and "doesn't work". Also I have to ask how this jar is being imported? Are you using maven? If so, can you share how it's being imported in the pom?

Comment: @jacobSlt.   Lets start about doesnt work, it say literally, this class cant be mocked. I check the class file of this class and it is not private neither static. This jar is working because i can use the real method and get an answer but i dont want to make the real call. And it is being imported as any other dependency groupid,artifact,version,scope. I am using maven to download this class from a private repository.  I could give u "real" details later.

Comment: @jacobslt.      It is possible that class file cant be mocked? Because they are compile or some mistery

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose the dependency with `PersonalExternalJar` in the `Person` class to mock it. One way to do that is using constructor.

So refactor the `Person` class to be like this:

```
public class Person {

     private final PersonalExternalJar pej;

     public Person (PersonalExternalJar pej) {
         this.pej = pej;
     }

     public void methodA(){
          *do some stuff*
           ArrayList people = pej.doSomething(AnyString,AnyString,AnyObject);
           *do some stuff*
           People2 p = new People2(); //  This class it is somewhere in my project lets say
           String SomePeople = p.doSomeStuff();

     }
}
```

In application code:

```
new Person(new PersonalExternalJar());
```

In your test:

```
PersonalExternalJar pejMocked = mock(PersonalExternalJar.class);
new Person(pejMocked);
```

You have also the option to use a `set` method instead of the `constructor`:

```
public class Person {
     private PersonalExternalJar pej;

     setPersonalExternalJar(PersonalExternalJar pej) {
         this.pej = pej;
     }
}
```

Comment: should also add from a design perspective, if `PersonalExternalJar` has no other role other than the one method then it should be explicitly injected vai the method instead of the constructor. Other than that what you have is accurate.

Comment: I already tried this. Making a constructor in person and passing PersonalExternalJar as parameter. But what gives me problems it is to use @mock annotation to that class or alternatively doing the Mockito.mock(PersonalExternalJar.class).   There is an error like i cant find the class.

Comment: @Nkosi, can you elaborate more? I always use constructor, because this show better all dependencies of the class and you don't have the risk to have some NPE because some dependency was not setted.

Comment: I have use the both constructor or set option. I am newbie but i did my research. Thanks!

Comment: @mariosalirrosas, what error? Maybe you have some scope problem in your project.

Comment: @dherik  what do you mean? I check the class files and PersonalExternalJar it is public and it has used in other projects. PersonalExternalJar it is used for example in person making a call to whatever. So what you mean by scope problem?

Comment: I mean a classpath problem. This problem with "class not found" only happens on your IDE or happens too in the build (mvn clean install)? Maybe is better to create a new question on SO, I don't think this not found class problem is related to the topic now.

Comment: Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.    --> When i changed the mockito version, the class i was trying to mock, got me this error.